# program compiles and runs but after sometime it stops working in cpp ,using typedef keyword

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

i am using this code but it is not running. 
it is not running in Dev C++.
it runs then blows up.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    struct Node* left;
    int data;
    struct Node* right;
};
typedef struct Node *node;
int main()
{
    node n;
    n->data = 4;
    cout << n->data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Ron DevC++ uses g++ as the compiler.

Comment: i got that, actually we need to provide memory for n then it could contain data field and others too.

Comment: idid that using malloc ,well new is also fine. thanks guys,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `n` before using it, something like:

```
node n = new Node;
```

Comment: Change allocate to initialise

Comment: @StoryTeller If you exclude typedef, `n` would be a pointer to a structure of type Node, which is not allocated - you get a segmentation violation running it. Author should do something like: `node n = new Node;`

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the `n` variable is just a pointer which points to who knows where. You need to assign it some memory address where it can read the data from or write to.
This should do the trick:

```
node n = new Node;
```

The `typedef struct Node *node;` might be a little confusing for you.
You can write:

```
Node* n = new Node;
```

And get rid off the typedef which is much more clear that the `n` is just a pointer and thus you need to assign it some address where it points to.